# Direct/Live Preview Like Stackoverflow?

Tags: javascript, textarea, live, preview

how do i do like Stackoverflow, when you type in this field, that the it previews directly under it?.. I have no idea how this have been made and i really like to do something like this to my website. 
I have a textarea that you edit, and then..? how to?

Thanks

Comment: Also take a look on their [blog](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=partner-pub-6254779591266030:wa6mxc6y8y6&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=wmd&sa=Search) [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wmd](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wmd) [http://wmd-editor.com/](http://wmd-editor.com/)

Comment: Does anyone use view source anymore?

Comment: @Niel N, it's too complicated, asking for the complete answer is much more easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jquery, in the header in a script tag:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#textbox-id').keypress(function(){
          $('#preview-id').html($(this).val());
        }
    });
```

Then, in your html:

```
<textarea id="textbox-id"></textarea>
<div id="preview-id"></div>
```

### Edit

Damn, beaten by a few seconds.  Also, wmdeditor is exactly it.

Comment: This does not work.. I get nothing output in the <div> .. I have it like this:
 <form action="javascript:profilinsert()" method="get">
 <textarea name="profiltekst" id="profiltekst" rows="17" cols="70" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px"><? echo $p["profiltekst"]; ?></textarea><br>
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Opdatér"/> 
 </form>  
  <div id="insert_response"></div>
  <div id="preview"></div>

And then ofcourse the script in <head + script tag..

Answer (score 2):

Simple, place a div element and then on the onMouseup of the text box you can have a jquery event move the info

```
<textarea id="entry" onmouseup="$('#output').html($('#entry').val())"></textarea>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: This approach would create lots of problem with page rendering unless you also HTMLEncode the data. http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/html/encode.html Imagine if you typed in <div>, the absense of a closing DIV may throw the page layout completely out.  That's not even mentioning the implications of SCRIPT tags unless you HTML encode.

Comment: and voila... you have just enabled XSS attack vectors on your site ;)

Comment: He didn't say anything about how he was saving them :P

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `keypress` event:

```
$('#in').keypress(function() {
    $('#out').text($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

see this,   http://jsfiddle.net/testtracker/2C3Zj/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textbox-id').on('keyup', function(){
      $('#preview-id').html($(this).val());
    });
});​
```